# Parsing precise answers of HTML with redundant tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm looking to parse the FAQ of [the Bert as a service](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service).

I'm interested by this HTML :

```html
<h5>
    <a id="user-content-q-how-do-you-get-the-fixed-representation-did-you-do-pooling-or-something" class="anchor" aria-hidden="true" href="#q-how-do-you-get-the-fixed-representation-did-you-do-pooling-or-something">
    <svg class="octicon octicon-link" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="16" height="16" aria-hidden="true">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9h1v1H4c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5S2.55 3 4 3h4c1.45">
        </path>
    </svg>
    </a>
    <strong>Q:</strong> How do you get the fixed representation? Did you do pooling or something?
</h5>
<p><strong>A:</strong> Yes, pooling is required to get a fixed representation of a sentence. In the default strategy <code>REDUCE_MEAN</code>, I take the second-to-last hidden layer of all of the tokens in the sentence and do average pooling.</p>
```

I have succeed to retrieve the questions separately of the answers. But the form of tag of the answers are not redundant. Here is my code to parse this HTML :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

wp = requests.get("https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service")
soup = BeautifulSoup(wp.text, "html.parser")

# Parse the questions    
results = soup.find_all("h5") 

questions = []
for result in results:
    question = result.contents[2]
    questions.append(question)

# Parse the answers
new_tag = soup.find_all("p")
new_tag = new_tag[114:165] # specify the tag of the answers


answers = []
for new in new_tag:
    answer = new.contents[1]
```

I have really bad forms for my answer as the `<p>` tag is really frequent.

Comment: Do you expect to return the code examples  in the answers as well as this makes things more complicated.

Comment: No, just like the answer of @Jack Fleeting, I would only the beginning of the answer. However, I don't want the `Q:` and `A:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run

```
for i in results:
  print(i.text)
  print(i.findNext('p').text)
```

You get (picking one q/a pair at random):

```
Q: Can I use multilingual BERT model provided by Google?
A: Yes.
```

You can then append these to your lists and go from there.

Comment: It's close to be perfect, I would like to delete the `Q:` and `A:`

Comment: @Jonor Just change the print statements to `print(i.text.replace('Q: ',''))` and 
   `print(i.findNext('p').text.replace('A: ',''))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the following

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

wp = requests.get("https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service")
soup = BeautifulSoup(wp.text, "lxml")
titles = [item.text.lstrip('Q: ') for item in soup.select('h5')]
initial_paras = [item.text.lstrip('A: ') for item in soup.select('h5 + p')]
print(len(titles), len(initial_paras))
```